# Trigger execution for foreign table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger, foreign-data-wrapper, postgres-fdw

I have two databases db1 and db2.db2 has foreign table, say tableA whose schema has been imported from db1. A trigger runs on tableA in db1 for every row update.
Now using postgres_fdw I can fetch the records from db2 but unable to update any record on tableA due to that trigger function.Update works fine in case I disable the trigger.I need that trigger for audit log.

Please suggest me a suitable suggestion to resolve the issue.I am using postgres 9.6.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: It can not find the log table in which the audit details are to be inserted.It shows relation [table_name] does not exists though the table is available in db1. @JGH

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user establishing the link has access to the audit tables.

You could also add the required schema to the trigger function search path:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION abc.mytrigger() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$BEGIN
 [...] -- do something in the xyz schema
  RETURN NEW;
END;$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql 
SET search_path = xyz;
```

Comment: Let me try this and I shall get back to you.